# How do I solve the following problem concerning primitive functions?

Tags: functions, derivatives, inverse-function

I need some help for the following problem:

> Let $F:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a primitive function for $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, where $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{x^4+2}$.
>   Prove that:
>
> a)$F$ is injective,
>
> b)$|F(x_1)-F(x_2)|\leq|x_1-x_2|$, $x_1,x_2>0$.

I managed to solve "a)" but I do not have any idea how to solve "b)". Can anyone help me?

Comment: (b) sounds unlikely; what if $x_2=-x_1$?

Comment: do you have computed $$F(x)$$?

Comment: I have not yet learnt how to integrate. I think it can be made without finding F(x).

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I understand what you are saying, but what if we exclude that case?

Comment: In which case what if $x_2$ is near $-x_1$? I think the statement is in error.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Let's say $x_1,x_2>0$

Comment: Why your tag is integration and you haven't learnt integrals?

Comment: I did not know what to put cause there is no antiderivative tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Formal_statement)

$F(x_2)-F(x_1)=F'(c)(x_2-x_1)=f(c)(x_2-x_1)$ for some $c\in(x_1,x_2)$

therefore

$|F(x_2)-F(x_1)|=|f(c)||x_2-x_1|\leq |x_2-x_1|$

because $f(x)\leq 1, \quad\forall x \in\mathbb{R}$

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how this fits in with "haven't learned integration yet," but:

$|F(x_1) - F(x_2)|$ is the area under the curve $y=f(x)$ above the $x$-axis and between $x_1$ and $x_2$.  That area has to be less than the width of the interval (which is $|x_1-x_2|$) times the maximum value of $f(x)$ (which is $1/2$.)

Answer (score 0):

Since $f(x)$ is a derivative of $F(x)$, we can say that $F$ is differentiable everywhere in the domain. Think of the problem of b) as that of finding a suitable Lipschitz coeffecient for the given function $F$. The largest possible absolute value of $f(x)$ is $\frac{1}{2}$ for $x = 0$. Thus, by the definition of differentiation,
$$sup\lim_{x_2 \to 0}\frac{|F(x_1+ x_2) - F(x_1)|}{|x_1 - x_2|} = \frac{1}{2}$$
note that the supremum above is taken over all $x_1\in \mathbb{R}$. This means that $|f(x)|$ is smaller than or equal to $g(x) = \frac{1}{2}$. Now, suppose that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are arbitrarily chosen, and without loss of generality, $x_1>x_2$. Then
$$\begin{align}|F(x_1)-F(x_2)|&=\left|\int_{x_2}^{x_1} f(x) dx\right|\\
&\leq \int_{x_2}^{x_1}|f(x)|dx\\
&\leq \int_{x_2}^{x_1} g(x) dx \quad (\because |f(x)|\leq g(x))\\
&=\int_{x_2}^{x_1} \frac{1}{2}dx\\
&=\frac{1}{2}|x_1-x_2|\\
&\leq\frac{1}{2}\left(|x_1+x_2|+|x_1 + x_2|\right)\\
&\leq|x_1+x_2|
\end{align}$$
Now, we have the desired result $|F(x_1)-F(x_2)| \leq |x_1+x_2|$ for all $x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ since the choice of $x_1$ and $x_2$ was arbitrary.